# Compare date from MySQL to date from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web app which users login to it.
Every time a specific user logs in, I store the login datetime in a MySQL db:

```
(yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss)
```

Each record in the db has a user_identifier and last_login_datetime.
However, I want to make sure that users can only login once a day.
I was thinking about comparing the time function in PHP to the datetime I have in the DB and see if the user was already logged on today.
If the user was logged on today, I'll kick him out.

How do I compare the record in the DB to the time function in PHP to see if the user was logged in already?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you do this entirely in the DB? It has all the date manipulation and comparison functions you could want.

Comment: SELECT * from users WHERE date_add(last_login_datetime, interval 1 day) < now() and username="" and password=...

Comment: You could do something like `SELECT logon_date=CURDATE() AS kick_out FROM users where user_id=xxx`.

Comment: "can only login once a day" - but what does this mean? Once every 24 hours? Once per calendar day? If the latter, which calendar day - the one on the server? The UTC calendar day? The one on the the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add something like this to conditions of the `SELECT` to validate a user's credentials when they login

```
... (AND DAY(last_login_datetime) != DAY(NOW()) OR MONTH(last_login_datetime) != MONTH(NOW()) OR YEAR(last_login_datetime) != YEAR(NOW()))
```

If the day, month, or year do not match today's day, month, and year, the select will return the user *(assuming the other credentials/conditions are valid)*. If no result is returned, the user's credentials were incorrect *or* the user has already logged in today - either way they should not be allowed to login according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not quite what you've asked for, but this can be done with strictly just SQL

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(created_on, NOW()) <= -1
```

This will return any users who have logged in more than 1 day ago. Of course you would limit it to the specific user you want and if the result is empty then deny them login privileges.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to compare dates in PHP for whatever reason, the best way to go about it is using [DateTime](http://www.php.net/DateTime), [DateTimeZone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) and [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) classes.

Reason for that is ease of calculating the differences, constructing the date object from various input dates and most important - time zones are taken into account too so you won't make a mistake when dealing with daylight savings.

How to:

```
$date = '2011-07-11 13:37:37';
$timezone = 'Europe/London';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss', $date, new DateTimeZone($timezone );
$now = new DateTime(time(), $timezone);

$diff = $date->diff($now); // You got the difference here. If the difference is less than 24h then attempt in the same day occurred.

if($diff->h < 24)
{
    // failure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in PHP, you can use strtotime() to convert to a timestamp (number of seconds since 1/1/1970), then compare as you want:

```
$time = strtotime($row['time']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from doing it completely on the database side since it is possible (and probably easier to do without shuffling it between SQL and PHP), the best thing you should do when working with formatted timestamps from two different platforms is to convert both timestamp strings to a uniform timestamp.

You can do this with [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime). I run into the situation often when I need to compare SQL server timestamps with server timestamps, so I just use good ol strtotime() when I need to bring it on the PHP side.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Snippet:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$dbDate = new DateTime('2011-07-11 12:00:00'); // DB Date as parameter

if($today == date_format($dbDate,'Y-m-d'))
{
    ; // Magic
}
```